# What is a famous study about Newton’s law cooling?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, kinematics, temperature

I am a high school student in the process of writing his report. I have finished the process of writing my report about newton’s law of cooling for a murder example and finding the time taken since the crime has happened but this time, I added a twist by adding that the temperature of the environment varies ±10F sinusoidally from a mean of 55F over a 24 hour period(in other words there is also a change in temperature of the surroundings). My problem at the moment, I came up with my own values for initial temperature etc. I think a better way is to find values from a real life example. If you have anything in mind for a real life example with real life values, please let me know so I can add the small twist in the results I got. Also if you don’t think this is the place to ask this question let me know if I can ask anywhere else on stack exchange.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! Sounds like a fun project! It is a bit unclear what you are asking about. Newton's law of cooling is usually applied to a hot isolated system (e.g. which does not continually produce additional heat, like a heater would). which cools by interacting with its environment. Do you have an object cooling down in your environment? Or are you trying to study how the environment reacts to a heating element which you place in it?

Comment: Hello there, sorry for not making my question clear but I will make the changes.

Comment: Depends - if I were your teacher,  I would like best to see how you approach the problem on your own, with whatever assumptions and equations you think make sense.

Comment: It's very unlikely to find a *report of real life case* of what you describe. A better idea would be to describe the physics/math of $\text{NLoC}$ in the case where the environment temperature is a simple function of time. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Oh ok. And @Gert , if you can please tell me how to do that that will be really helpful.

Comment: Ok, I will do that now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for an interesting question!

You are trying to solve a rather complicated problem involving a differential equation and an external driving force. I will derive the solution below. If you cannot follow the math, don't worry, I'll add a more qualitative description at the end.

Newton's law of cooling states that:
$$
\frac{dT}{dt} = -k(T-T_e)
$$
where $k$ is some proportionality constant, $T$ is the temperature of the body, $T_e$ is the temperature of the environment and $t$ is the time elapsed.

This makes sense mathematically because if $T = T_e$, then $dT/dt = 0$, i.e., the temperature stops changing once the body reaches the same temperature as the environment. Furthermore, if $T>T_e$, the derivative is always negative, so the temperature of the body is decreasing.

In your case, $T_e$ is a function of temperature, as $T_e = T_{e0}+ A\sin(\omega t)$, where I'm assuming that the environment is at $T=55$°F at $t = 0$, so $T_{e0} = 55$°F and $A = 10$°F. Here, $\omega$ is such that after 24 hours, $\omega t = 2\pi$. So if $t$ is measured in hours, $\omega = 2\pi/24$.

Thus, the differential equation you are trying to solve is:
$$
\frac{dT}{dt} = -kT + kT_e = -kT+kT_{e0}+kA\sin(\omega t).
$$
You can understand this as follows: the rate of change of the body temperature at time $t$ is directly proportional to the difference of the current body temperature and the temperature of the environment. This is called an inhomogeneous linear first-order differential equation. There is a good description of them [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/deinhom.html).

So how do we find the equation $T(t)$ satisfying this differential equation? Let's assume that the initial temperature of the body $T_0$ is fixed (for example, 98.6°F is a typical body temperature when the person is alive). We first solve the homogeneous case, that is, the case where the temperature of the environment is zero. The equation
$$
\frac{dT}{dt} = -kT
$$
has a well-known, standard solution:
$$
T_h(t) = \alpha e^{-kt},
$$
where $\alpha$ is a temperature we have to figure out at the end.

How do we deal with the additional variation? We have to "guess" a specific solution. Because the inhomogeneous part is a trigonometric function plus a constant function, we guess a specific solution $T_s(t) = B\sin(\omega t)+C\cos(\omega t)+D$ for general parameters $B$, $C$ and $D$. Differentiating this gives:
$$
T_s'(t) = \omega B\cos(\omega t)-\omega C\sin(\omega t).
$$

Comparison to the general equation gives:
$$
\omega B\cos(\omega t)-\omega C\sin(\omega t) = -k(B\sin(\omega t)+C\cos(\omega t)+D-T_{e0})+kA\sin(\omega t).
$$

Comparing coefficients gives:
$$
\omega B=-kC;
$$
$$
\omega C = kB-kA;
$$
$$
D = T_{e0},
$$
from which it follows that $B = -\frac{k^2}{\omega^2} (B-A)$, or equivalently:
$$
B = \frac{k^2}{\omega^2+k^2}A
$$
and also:
$$
C = -\frac{\omega k}{\omega^2 + k^2}A.
$$
So a specific solution is:
$$
T_s(t) = \frac{k^2}{\omega^2+k^2}A \sin(\omega t) -  \frac{\omega k}{\omega^2 + k^2}A \cos(\omega t)+T_{e0}.
$$
The full solution is the sum of the two solutions:
$$
T(t) = T_h(t)+T_s(t) = \alpha e^{-kt}+T_{e0}+\frac{k^2}{\omega^2+k^2}A \sin(\omega t) -  \frac{\omega k}{\omega^2 + k^2}A \cos(\omega t).
$$
To fix the parameter $\alpha $, we require that $T(0) = T_0$, the initial temperature of the body. This gives:
$$
\alpha + T_{e0}-\frac{\omega k}{\omega^2 + k^2 } A = T_{0},
$$
so that:
$$
\alpha = T_{0}-T_{e0}+\frac{\omega k}{\omega^2 + k^2 } A.
$$
Our final solution is:
$$
T(t) = T_h(t)+T_s(t),
$$
which explicitly is:
$$
T(t) = (T_{0}-T_{e0}+\frac{\omega k}{\omega^2 + k^2 } A)e^{-kt}+T_{e0}+\frac{k^2}{\omega^2+k^2}A \sin(\omega t) -  \frac{\omega k}{\omega^2 + k^2}A \cos(\omega t).
$$

---

So what does this solution mean? First, note that as $t$ becomes very large, the exponential term becomes very small, so the homogeneous solution goes to zero. Thus, if you turn off the sinusoidal variation ($A= 0$), the body tends to the temperature $T_{e0}$ as expected. Furthermore, the shape of the solution for large $t$ depends on the ratio of $\omega$ to $k$. This ratio tells you how quickly the body reacts to the external temperature variations. If $k \gg \omega$, then there is almost no delay in the body reacting to the external temperature variations, and the solution (for large $t$) tends to:
$$T_e = T_{e0}+A\sin(\omega t).$$
That is, the temperature of the body follows the temperature of the environment. On the other hand, if $\omega \gg k$, then the solution tends to $T_{e0}$ (again for large $t$), i.e., the body does not really respond to the changes in environmental temperature.

I realize this may be too much math for your report, but what I am trying to show is that this is a complicated system! What the temperature profile looks like depends crucially on how fast the body reacts to changing temperature and how much time has passed. Initially, the exponential behavior dominates, but then the oscillatory phase begins, where the behavior depends on how quickly your system can react to the change of temperature in the environment.

So what is $k$ for a human body? This will depend on a host of factors, including how much clothes they are wearing, what the surface area is and what the muscle to fat ratio is. However, you may be able to estimate $k$ from the solution above, or at least qualitatively discuss which regime $k$ should fall into.

Finally, I have plotted the solutions for two choices of $k$ below. I fix $T_{0} = 98.6$°F, $T_{e0} = 55$°F, $\omega = 2\pi/24$, and $A=10$°F.

For $k = 5 \gg 2\pi/24$, the solution in the exponential regime is:
[image: k=5]

Whereas for $k = 0.1 \ll 2\pi/24$, the solution in the exponential regime is:
[image: k=0.1]

Finally, running for a long time for different $k$:
[image: Long k]
where the red curve is the temperature of the environment. Notice the differences in the amplitude, frequency, and length of the exponential regime. Notice also that the $k=5$ curve follows the environment almost perfectly (the blue curve is hidden under the red). For the large-$k$ case, the body reacts quickly to the changing temperature, so after an initial cooling phase, the body has the same temperature as the environment. For small $k$, the body and the environment are out of phase, so the body both cools and heats at a different rate than the environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @G.Lang , although this question might be dumb from me, but I don’t have an idea why I used the approach of temperature changing sinusoidally.

Comment: A physicists might argue that it is because it leads to solvable equations ;) No but in all seriousness, this approach is not as artificial as you might think . One could imagine modeling daily temperature variations by a trigonometric function. It's probably coldest around midnight, warmer towards midday, and cold at midnight again. You would have to adapt your trigonometric variation accordingly, but it should not change much of the physics. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi. Your answer is nice but marrred by your mutilation of NLoC. NLoC is not just an exponential decay function. $k$ has real meaning and is composed of several Real World constants that can be found from theory or experiment. By simplifying this you are misleading those who have little understaning of NLoC.

Comment: But it is precisely just an exponential decay function! That's the beauty of it - the shape of the curve is independent of all those pesky real world constants. To reliably calculate $k$ you would need to take into account what the person was wearing, the exact heat transfer mechanisms etc. That would lead to far too much uncertainty in a real murder case. Instead, you would simply measure the exponential decay as a function of time and then fit $k$ and $T_0$ without needing to know any real parameters. Only in a carefully controlled lab would you be able to estimate $k$ purely from theory.

Comment: Though with that said, I think your estimation of k is highly insightful and a very nice addition, and I should probably have discussed this. But I don't think the estimate would be sufficiently reliable to extract T0 from real data, unless your experiment was very carefully controlled.

Answer (score 1):

> I added a twist by adding that the temperature of the environment
> varies ±10F sinusoidally from a mean of 55F over a 24 hour

**The question is 'what will this mean from the PoV of a pathologist trying to determine the time of death of a person?'**

We start with the implicit version of $\text{NLoC}$:

$$\dot{Q}=hA[T(t)-T_{env}(t)]\tag{1}$$

where $T_{env}(t)$, is the environment's temperature as a function of time, here:

$$T_{env}(t)=T_0+T_a\sin\omega t\tag{2}$$

We also have:

$$\dot{Q}=\frac{\text{d}Q}{\text{d}t}=-mc_p\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}$$

(we assume $c_p=\text{constant}$ over the temperature interval of concern)

So that with $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have:

$$-mc_p\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}=hA[T(t)-T_0-T_a\sin\omega t]$$

Often we set:

$$\frac{1}{\tau}=\frac{hA}{mc_p}$$

where $\tau$ is the so-called *characteristic time*. Simplifying and rearranging  we get:

$$T'+\frac{T}{\tau}-\frac{T_0}{\tau}=\frac{T_a}{\tau}\sin\omega t\tag{3}$$

To simplify a little, set:

$$\Theta=T-T_0$$

$$\text{d}\Theta=\text{d}T$$

So that:

$$\Theta'+\frac{\Theta}{\tau}=\frac{T_a}{\tau}\sin\omega t\tag{4}$$

Because the ODE $(4)$ is *not homogeneous* it cannot be solved by separation of variables. However, it can be solved with an [integrating factor](https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mathcentre-ode.pdf):

$$I=e^{\int \frac{1}{\tau}\text{d}t}=e^{t/\tau}$$

Now multiply the ODE with $I$:

$$\Theta'e^{t/\tau}+\frac{\Theta}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}=e^{t/\tau}\frac{T_a}{\tau}\sin\omega t$$

$$\Rightarrow \int \Big(\Theta'e^{t/\tau}+\frac{\Theta}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}\Big)\text{d}t=\int\Big(e^{t/\tau}\frac{T_a}{\tau}\sin\omega t\Big)\text{d}t$$
$$\Rightarrow e^{t/\tau}\Theta=\int\Big(e^{t/\tau}\frac{T_a}{\tau}\sin\omega t\Big)\text{d}t=\frac{T_a}{\tau}\int \Big(e^{t/\tau}\sin\omega t\Big)\text{d}t$$

The last RHS integral is tedious and yields:

$$\Rightarrow e^{t/\tau}\Theta=\frac{T_a}{\tau}\Big(\frac{\tau e^{t/\tau} \sin\omega t}{\tau^2\omega^2+1}-\frac{\tau^2\omega e^{t/\tau} \cos\omega t}{\tau^2\omega^2+1}+C_1\Big)$$
where $C_1$ is the integration constant. Dividing through with $e^{t/\tau}$ we finally get:

$$\boxed{\Theta(t)=C_1\frac{T_a}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}+\frac{T_a \sin\omega t}{\tau^2\omega^2+1}-\frac{T_a\tau \omega  \cos\omega t}{\tau^2\omega^2+1}}$$

And of course:

$$T=\Theta+T_0$$

$$\boxed{T(t)=T_0+C_1\frac{T_a}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}+\frac{T_a}{\tau^2\omega^2+1}( \sin\omega t-\tau \omega  \cos\omega t)}$$

$C_1$ has to be determined from the initial condition $T=37^\circ C$ at $t=0$.

---

Alternatively and much easier to the above derivation is to determine the material constants $\tau$, $\omega$ and $T_a$, then enter the ODE into Wolfram alpha, [as I did here for a related question][2].

---

So what does all this mean for our intrepid pathologist?

The term $C_1\frac{T_a}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}$ tends to $0$ at a rate depending on $\tau$.

Once $C_1\frac{T_a}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}\approx 0$ then $T$ is given by:

$$T(t)\approx T_0+\frac{T_a}{\tau^2\omega^2+1}( \sin\omega t-\tau \omega  \cos\omega t)$$

This now means, because the pathologist has no knowledge of $T_a$ or $\omega$, that there is *uncertainty* on the final temperature of the body and that makes determining the time of death harder. More accurate determinations of the time of death (ToD) are made when the environment's temperature is more or less constant.

---

So let's put some bones on them bones, shall we?

Firstly calculate:

$$\frac{1}{\tau}=\frac{hA}{mc_p}$$

For an object close to room temperature and without forced convection we find:

$$h\approx5\space\mathrm{W m^{-2}K^{-1}}$$

Further for an adult body some googling shows that:  $A=1.9\approx\space\mathrm{m^{2}}$, $m=80\space\mathrm{kg}$ and $c_p \approx 4,200\space\mathrm{Jkg^{-1}K^{-1}}$.

So the inverted characteristic time $1/\tau$ and converted to hours gives:

$$\frac{1}{\tau}=0.102\space\mathrm{hour^{-1}}$$

Calculating the solution to the ODE and plotting it gives:

[image: Tempplot]

In the temperature range $\text{A}$ to $\text{B}$ the ToD can be estimated roughly from the simple ODE, without the forcing term. But in the range $\text{C}$ to $\text{D}$ (and beyond), the final temperature becomes uncertain and estimating ToD much harder.